# Azure API Management forward-request Not Honoring follow-redirects

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management with the following backend policy:

```
<backend>
    <forward-request timeout="10" follow-redirects="true" />
</backend>
```

When testing in Postman, I'm still receiving a 308 Permanent Redirect. I thought that follow-redirects followed a backend redirect response. Why is it getting passed back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

[follow-redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#attributes-1):Specifies whether redirects from the backend service are followed by the gateway **or returned to the caller**.

As the article said, when you follow-redirects as true, it will returned to the client.

Comment: "Specifies whether redirects from the backend service are followed by the gateway or returned to the caller." I read that as saying that a setting of true instructs APIM to follow the redirects. I've tried both settings and neither one is working as expected.

Comment: That's how I read it as well @JohnBoldt did you ever get it to work?

Comment: Ok this worked for me calling the API in code and via postman but it didn't work in the browser .. but I've just tried it again and it now works, so I guess it was down to a cached response.  FYI I have follow-redirects set to true.